# Why can't I use "yield" operator to return a lazy list in IValueConverter?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Suppose I have the following class:

```
public class Values {
    public string Value1 {get;set;}
    public string Value2 {get;set;}
    public string Value3 {get;set;}
}
```

Now I want to bind this object's values to a GUI component's ItemsSource in a specific order, using an IValueConverter:

```
public class ValuesToListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var valuesObj = (Values ) value;
        yield return valuesObj.Value1;
        yield return valuesObj.Value3;
        yield return valuesObj.Value2;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

The body of 'Convert' cannot be an iterator block because 'object' is not an iterator interface type.

Is there any way to lazily create this list in an IValueConverter? Or do I have to do:

```
return new List<string> { valuesObj.Value1, valuesObj.Value3, valuesObj.Value2 }
```

Comment: `yield` statements can only occur in methods returning `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerator`. You *could* create a lazy private method and then return its result from `Convert`, but it's unlikely the caller would know what to do with the return value. I would just return the `List`.

Comment: Thanks @dlev adding the private method worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterator blocks are only defined when the return type is one of:

- IEnumerable
- IEnumerable-of-T
- IEnumerator
- IEnumerator-of-T

The generated iterator then becomes a state machine that fulfils a very specific contract that provides deferred execution and lazy iteration of multiple values.

None of this applies if returning object: you need to return one object *now*.

If your converter needs to return an IEnumerable, then you can do that - but you need to add a second (private) method for the iterator block - and the return type must be one of those listed above.